# I want to reflect real time changed user nickname when chatting?

Tags: javascript, firebase, react-native, google-cloud-firestore

The previous chat data contains the pre-change nickname, so it is not reflected in real time when changing the nickname.
What method should I use to make the nickname change in real time even the chat before changing the nickname?.

Do I have to change the nickname information in the chat data every time I change my nickname?

```
Firebase.usersRef
  .doc(Firebase.currentUser.email)
  .update({'nickname': nickname})
  .then(() ⇒ {
    Firebase.chatsRef
      .where('user.name', '==', Firebase.currentUser.email)
      .get()
      .then((querySnapshot) ⇒ {
        querySnapshot.forEach(doc ⇒ 
          // Changing the nickname
        )
      })
  })
  .catch(err => console.log(err));
```

Answer (score 1):

You should identify the user for each chat message by a so-called stable identifier, which apparently their nickname is not in your case.

Given that you seem to be using Firebase Authentication, the most common stable identifier for a user is their UID, which you can get with `Firebase.currentUser.uid`. So in addition to the nickname for the user, also store their UID in each document. Then use the UID for selecting the messages for a user, and use the nickname only to display in the UI,